# lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7

Tags: flutter, package, flutter-dependencies

lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
Runnable runnable = () -> events.success(connectivity.getNetworkType());
^
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
1 error
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

i am using connectivity plus package in flutter, i am facing the issue

lambda expressions are not supported in -source 7
Runnable runnable = () -> events.success(connectivity.getNetworkType());
^
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)